# Convert PDF to Text and Push to a Google Sheet using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace

I receive a PDF report weekly that I would like to automate into a Google Sheet Workbook using App Script.

I was able to successfully pull the PDF from my Gmail account and extract the text I need but I am having trouble taking the "Table" from the PDF and writing it to Google Sheets.

I used a split function to extract only what I need, and create an "extract" variable that I would like to slice up and use to reconstruct in google sheets. The table extract comes out like this:

Groups
Team A 1,058 1,058
Team B 757 757
Team C 179 6,830 7,009
Team D 1,359 1,359
Total 179 10,004 10,183

Ideally I would like the table to look like this in google sheets:

```
Teams   X   Y   Total
Team A  1,058       1,058
Team B  757 757 1,514
Team C  179 6,830   7,009
Team D  1,359       1,359
Total   179 10,004  10,183
```

Primary Question: How can I construct my text extract into an Array that I can push / write to google sheets?

Below is the script I have so far, but I can't seem to write the data to google sheet using the sheet.getrange.setvalues(data). I was expecting to at least be able to push the text to google sheets so maybe I could manipulate it there with formulas.

I receive an error "TypeError: sheet.getrange is not a function". Referring to my primary question above, do I need to reformat the data in a way that can write out correctly to google sheets?

``

```
function importPDFFromGmail() {
 var threads = GmailApp.search("TEST PDF PULL"); // enter search criteria here
  var messages = threads[0].getMessages();
  var message = messages[messages.length - 1];  // Takes the last thread in the email chain
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];  

  // Is the attachment a PDF file
      attachment.setContentTypeFromExtension();
      if (attachment.getContentType() === "application/pdf") {
          var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('<Sheet ID>').getSheetByName('PDF TEST');
        
         var blob = attachment.getAs(MimeType.PDF);  
         var filetext = pdfToText( blob, {keepTextfile: false} );
         var extract = filetext.split('Sum')[1].split('Sum')[0]; //  part between 'Sum' and 'Sum'
         
         var lines = extract.split("\n");
         // var extract_delimited = lines.map(function(lin){return lin.split(" ")}); 
         
         var data = lines.map(function(lin){return lin.split(" ")});  
   
        
         sheet.clear();
         sheet.getrange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
      }
          //  console.log("extract");
          // console.log(extract)
          //  console.log("lines");
          // console.log(lines)
          //  console.log("extract delimited");
          // console.log(extract_delimited;          
};
```

``

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `pdfToText`? And, where is the error line of `TypeError: sheet.getrange is not a function` in your showing script?

Comment: The Type Error kicks in at during line 23. sheet.getrange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length.setValues(data);

Comment: The pdfToText details, imagine a letter head at the top, in email format and then the data I extracted is that Groups Team A 1,058 1,058 Team B 757 757 Team C 179 6,830 7,009 Team D 1,359 1,359 Total 179 10,004 10,183 section but it looks like a table in the PDF

Comment: Replace `sheet.getrange` with `sheet.getRange`.

Comment: That helped continue through, but now I am getting the following error, which I believe has to do with the data not being an array?" 
Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 4 but the range has 2."

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that the discussion has already been advanced and an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing discussion and answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First fix the typo in `sheet.getRange()`.

Your `String.split()` call will get rows that vary in length, while `Range.setValues()` expects a 2D array where every row is of the same length. You can set the length of all rows to the common max value like this:

```js
  const numColumns = Math.max(...data.map(row => row.length));
  data.forEach(row => row.length = numColumns);
  sheet.getRange('A1')
    .offset(0, 0, data.length, numColumns)
    .setValues(data);
```

Comment: This leads to another error, "Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 2 but the range has 5."

Comment: Right, you will need to set `row.length`. Edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am self taught in apps script / coding so I am still learning how to do more advanced techniques. This is a really big help. I was able to print out the table!  Thank you!